# Create object using Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I receive from an external source strings that are pretty much the signature of the constructor of the object. They contain the class name and the parameters.

For example:

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo(int x, int y, int z) {
    // do something
  }
}

public class Bar {
  public Bar (int x, boolean bool) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Let's say I have many classes like this, and I want to create object from these classes based on the string I receive (that contains the class name and the paramters). Can this be done?

I know I can get the class using something like this:

```
String className = "myClass";
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(className);
//Constructor<?> ctor = myClass.getConstructor();
//Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
```

But how can I instantiate the object if I don't know at compile time how many paramters the constructor will have and of which type they will be? By the way, the classes from which I want to create the object will most likely have only one constructor available. But each class might have a different constructor compared to the other.

Comment: You can then use reflection to get the number and types of arguments for the constructor. But at some point, you will need to determinate the values to pass...

Comment: The values that I want to pass will be parsed from the String that I receive: it might look something like this: "Foo(4,5,7) " or "Bar(1,true)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem because the `newInstance()` method receives an array:

```
public T newInstance(Object ... initargs)
```

So you just initialize an array containing all the arguments and pass it

something like this:

```
String[] argsAsString = readValuesFromString(data);
Object[] args = new Object[argAsString.length()];
int i = 0;
Class<?>[] paramTypes = ctor.getParameterTypes();
for (String argStr: argsAsString) {
    args[i] = convertStringToActualType(argStr, paramTypes[i]);
    i++;
}

ctor.newInstance(args);
```

You probably need to call `getConstructors()` on the class and then try to find the constructor with the correct number of arguments. This will work only if you dont have two or more constructors with the same number of arguments.
Then the `convertStringToActualType()` should know how to convert the string value to the actual parameter.. for example if it's boolean field `Boolean.valueOf(argStr)' etc - example:

```
Object convertStringToActualType(String arg, Class<?> type) {
    if (type == String.class)
        return arg;
    if (type == Boolean.class)
        return Boolean.valueOf(arg);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("type " + type.getSimpleName() + " not supported");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I completed the code you showed as an example and tried to run it. However I get the following `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Boolean` when I try to do `arguments[i] = convertStringToActualType(argStr, paramTypes[i]);`. It seems like the array can't store Boolean as it expects something else?

Comment: It seems the problem was here `Object[] args = new String[argAsString.length()];`. Should be `Object[] args = new Object[argsAsString.length];`

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo. Fixed